# .NET C# .UseSqlite EF Core context.Database.EnsureCreated() throws exception with MySQL unsigned property

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

We have a MySQL database with some tables containing unsigned properties, like:

| Column | Type | Nullable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user_id | int(10) unsigned | NO |

As a database provider, we are using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 6.0.2.
And as an ORM, we are making use of Entity Framework Core 6.0.22.0

When trying to perform tests using Sqlite (microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlite\6.0.22) it is throwing an exception on `context.Database.EnsureCreated();` saying:

> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: 'SQLite Error 1: 'near "unsigned": syntax error'.'

So, I am not sure but is Sqlite unable to create tables which contains unsigned fields?

I am trying to create a test that performs some operations on a Database, like get, delete, and executes commands (procedures), but during the database provider tables initialization steps it is breaking.
Apparently Sqlite does not support MySql unsigned columns.

The (EF Core) entity configuration is like:

```
builder.Property(e => e.UserId)
    .HasColumnName("user_id")
    .HasColumnType("int(10) unsigned")
    .IsRequired();
```

I am new on this project and the configurations are already done.

So, based on Microsofts documentation we are encouraged to use SQLite in-memory for tests purposes.

"it's usually a good idea to use SQLite's in-memory database feature when testing, since it provides easy isolation between tests, and does not require dealing with actual SQLite files."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/testing-without-the-database#sqlite-in-memory

Comment: There's no code but the problem is pretty clear. SQLite is a completely different database product from MySQL, with different types. EF doesn't specify *product-specific* types either, unless you force it. If you do, you lose the ability to target other database products

Comment: How did you specify `int(10) unsigned`? C# has no such types. Had you used the [Precision](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#precision-and-scale) attribute you wouldn't get such an error. This suggests you hard-coded the product-specific type with eg `HasColumnType` or `TypeName` in the `Column` attribute

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what kind of assurance do you get by performing unit testing using sqlite if the production code will run on mysql?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I am new on the project and the EF entities models were already configured, it is using this unsigned because it is unsigned in the MySQL DB. But I am reading a Microsoft webpage that is instructing to use Sqlite for tests purposes (I updated the description), and due that I am facing this problem.

Comment: `.HasColumnType("int(10) unsigned")` uses a MySQL type. If you want to use a different database you'll have to exclude that call. All property configuration calls, including `IsRequired()` accept *and* return a `PropertyBuilder` which means you can store the intermediate builder in a variable and add the type based on a flag or preprocessor symbol, the same way you use eg: `#if DEBUG ...`

Comment: I Faced exactly the same issue, i managed the problem by an architectural solution,

Answer (score 2):

`int(10) unsigned` is specific to MySQL and won't work on any other database. All property configuration methods return a `PropertyBuilder` though, which means you can configure a property in steps, and include the column type based on a condition, eg :

```
var idProperty=builder.Property(e => e.UserId)
    .HasColumnName("user_id")
    .IsRequired();
if (someCondition)
{
    idProperty.HasColumnType("int(10) unsigned");
}
```

**Conditional Compilation**

You can also use [conditional compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#conditional-compilation) based on a preprocessor symbol like DEBUG or a custom one, eg :

```
#if DEBUG
idProperty.HasColumnType("int(10) unsigned");
#endif
```

or

```
#if MYTEST
idProperty.HasColumnType("int(10) unsigned");
#endif
```

You can [define](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#defining-symbols) the MYTEST symbol with `#define MYTEST` in the source code, the `/define` compiler option or the [DefineConstants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/language#defineconstants) element in csproj

**Partial Methods/OnModelCreatingPartial**

Another possibility is to use [partial methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods#partial-methods) to perform any extra configuration code. You can define a method as partial and provide the actual implementation in another file:

```
partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
```

If no implementation is provided, the call is removed by the compiler. This is already used by EF Core scaffolding [as this blog post explains](https://irina.codes/extending-ef-core-dbcontext/). A scaffolded DbContext contains :

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }
    
    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
```

You can use this to extract the type definitions for specific properties to a separate file, eg one per database, and exclude/include files based on a condition in `csproj`, eg :

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="DbTypes\MyContext.Sqlite.cs" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'" />
</ItemGroup>
```

or

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="DbTypes\**" />
    <Compile Include="DbTypes\MyContext.Sqlite.cs" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Test'" />
</ItemGroup>
```

You aren't restricted to just the Debug and Release configurations. You can create [as many build configurations as needed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/understanding-build-configurations?view=vs-2022), eg a Test configuration whose settings are copied from Debug

Comment: That is awesome.
Thank you very much for this answer. It is gonna help me a lot.

Comment: That is the best solution, what you can do if you have a lot of old migrations ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are corresponding affinities for the traditional unsigned relational type as indicated in the Microsoft documentation: [Microsoft.Data.Sqlite Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/types)

I hope it was helpful to you

Comment: Hi!
Thank you for your answer. I guess it will help me.